# moving an image by a button in Xcode 8

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, xcode8

I am trying to move a picture in Xcode 8. I have the code for it, but the image won't move when the button is pressed. Can someone please help me solve the problem for the picture not moving.

```
import UIKit

class Level2ViewController: UIViewController {


 var image = UIImage(named: "ballon.png")

     var imageView = UIImageView(image: "ballon")//initialize properly, this is just for reference



    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

            self.imageView.frame.origin.x += 50

    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

Comment: Where do you initially set the frame of your `UIImageView`?

Comment: Did you set any constraints to the imageView?

Comment: Does the code inside your `buttonPressed` function executes? You can put a break break point on that line to see if the app stops at that break point, if not then chances are your button's `onTouchUpInside` event is not connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete your button from your code and then right click on your button and click on the "x" to remove the connection to the old code.
[image]

Now add the button back. I think your button was setup wrong.
when you right click the botton look and see what  the Send Event was.
It should be setup this way.

If this is the answer you were looking for don't forget to except the answer.

[image]

Comment: only prolem is that I'm using a single view application

Comment: Did you delete the button and redo it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I see it.. You need to control drag your imageView to your code and connect it as an outlet and then move the imageView outlet. you are moving the variable.

[image]

[image]

If this is the answer you were looking for don't forget to except the answer.